# How to access web application from XAMPP from public ip?

Tags: apache, xampp, web-hosting

I have built an php web app and deployed in XAMPP Apache server,now i want it to test it with multiple users. so i have planned to give access through using public ip. what configuration changes should i make in apache server to give access to users to web application?

multiple users may range between 25 to 70 users

Comment: you probably need to change the firewall settings instead. Also, does your computer have public IP (normally computer within a network uses private IP assigned by routers / switches)?

Comment: @Raptor yes it has a public ip.. it is dedicated for web application development.